# Why WYSIWYG Editor removing http://.. code in joomla

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

In joomla i using plugin Editor - TinyMCE

Ex: when i input value is : `http://test.com/images/background.png`

=> output remove `http://test.com`

result finally is `/images/background.png`

How to keep http://test.com when using this plugin, how to fix it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In plugin Editor - TinyMCE change `URLs` from `relative` to `absolute`